# UILabel truncating string even with required priority for content compression on iPhone 5c. But works fine in the simulator and iPad(device)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

This seems to be a weird issue. I have a UILabel which can contain multiple line text loaded from a back-end which has following constraints-

[image: Constraints]

But only on the iPhone 5c device(on iOS 8.0.2), the label is retaining the initial height given to the constraint and is truncating the rest of the content. But the same constraints work fine on the simulator and on an iPad. Is there something wrong constraint-wise or a problem from the device?

Screenshots of the same:-

iPhone 5c(Device) -

[image: iPhone5c-device]

iPhone 5s(Simulator) -

[image: iPhone5s-simulator]

iPad(Device) -

[image: iPad-device]

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my device to iOS 8.4 and now the issue seems to have resolved. There must have been some issues in 8.0.2.